# Как написать первое число этого месяца в php?

Tags: php

Как написать первое число этого месяца в php, чтобы месяц автоматом менялся исходя из текущего месяца. Допустим мне надо так YYYY-MM-01, то-бишь, чтобы менялся год и месяц, в зависимости от текущих значений даты.

Comment: `date('Y-m-01')`

Comment: Мне месяц обязательно с нулем нужен

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php - `m  Порядковый номер месяца с ведущим нулём  от 01 до 12`

Comment: @Lexx918 оформите ответом, я приму, спасибо, с уважением

Comment: в мануале же быстрее было бы прочитать О.о

Comment: @Эдуард возможно. Но я не знал что правильно в поиске вбивать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

> m     Порядковый номер месяца с ведущим нулём     от 01 до 12

```
date('Y-m-01')
```